# How could `mvn package` failed with compilation failure while `mvn compile` would have passed

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, command-line-interface, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a maven spring-boot multi-module project https://github.com/JiahuaZhang/maven-spring-boot-mutli-module-question.

For the `mvn clean test`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for dummy 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] dummy .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.094 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.884 s]
[INFO] foo ................................................ SUCCESS [  2.987 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For `mvn clean package`

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for dummy 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] dummy .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.661 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.673 s]
[INFO] foo ................................................ FAILURE [  0.178 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.731 s
[INFO] Finished at 2023-02-04T20:04:51-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project foo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

How could I get a compilation error on the `package` phase when the `compile` phase already passed?

For this project, in IntelliJ IDEA, I am able to run `CommonApplication` and `FooApplication`, and I have verified both apps' functionalities. For CommonApplication, I am able to access `/common` endpoint and connect to the `ws://localhost:8080/ws/common` web socket. For FooApplication, I am able to access the `/common` endpoint, `ws://localhost:8080/ws/common`, and also the `/foo` endpoint (since the Foo module depends on the Common module).

How could I `package` this project properly? I hope I can run `CommonApplication` or `FooApplication` through a single jar. For example, running `java -jar foo.jar` would bootstrap the spring-boot application, `/common`, `/foo`, and `ws://localhost:8080/ws/common` would be accessible locally.

P.S.
My Java and maven version info:

```
java --version
openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.7 (b89d5959fcde851dcb1c8946a785a163f14e1e29)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.7/libexec
Java version: 14.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/sdkman-cli/5.16.0/libexec/candidates/java/14.0.2-open
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: `clean` removes what `compile` did

Comment: you have a lot of warnings during the build like `com.example.dummy:common:${rversion}, ...` which will not work... furthermore if you into sub directories it does not really make sense only if done a `mvn install` before....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dummy</name>
  <description>dummy</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <rversion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</rversion>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.4</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>foo</module>
  </modules>
  <!--
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
-->
</project>
```

### common/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example.dummy</groupId>
  <artifactId>common</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>common</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>common</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### foo/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example.dummy</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>foo</name>
  <description>foo</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.dummy</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: bad idea to define the version of all the spring boot parts manually...they are defined via the spring-boot parent ... don't do that.. Better use the BOM setup instead of manually doing it so....

Comment: @khmarbaise, Yes, you are right. My first version of the answer was to refer to this: **Creating a Multi Module Project** (https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/).  But the referenced answer is far from the original setting of @ hamidie, so I modified a version close to the original setting of @ hamidie, which is the current version.